# Ubuntu Unity's status icons api?

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, pygtk, ubuntu-11.04

I noticed the Unity sidebar in newer Ubuntu versions can have a status bar and a number beside it. For example, the Update Manager shows a status bar in the center, and number of updates available, in the icon. How do you access this icon from a PyGTK app?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called the LauncherAPI. This will also allow you to flash the icon with an urgent notice, or add entries to the icon context menu.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI

On that page there is a good example written in Python. You will need to use the gi python module to talk over dbus. You can also talk directly over the lower level DBUS api.

```
from gi import Unity
launcher = Unity.LauncherEntry.get_for_desktop_id ("evolution.desktop")
launcher.set_property("count", 124)
launcher.set_property("count_visible", False)
```